# how to let custom string shown in the drop down in form.collection_select

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am working on ruby & rails. 
My user model is stored with firstname, and lastname. Right now, I want to search from a collection of uses, and the search is in a form using form_for. I would like the drop down string show the user's full name and also ordered by user **full name**. How to do with that?
currently, I only know how to order it by last name, and show last name.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <%= f.label 'First Choice'%>
        <%= f.collection_select :first, User.order(:lastname), :lastname, :lastname, include_blank: true %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: You probably should not name the column / association `first` as that can lead to some really confusing code and potential conflicts. For example `User.first.first` is a major WTF moment. Give it a descriptive name like `first_choice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a full_name instance method to user model to access it with object.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  def full_name
    first_name.to_s + last_name.to_s
  end
end
```

Then you can use the collection select like below -

```
<%= f.collection_select :first, User.order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc), :id, :full_name, , include_blank: true %>
```

Comment: Mark it accepted so that someone can get help when visits this question.